# Can I get the company name/logo with the LinkedIn API?

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

If I have a LinkedIn organization id, like 123456 can I get the company name or logo?

I can see that it could be done in the previous API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-lookup-api

`GET https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizations/{organization ID}`

But it is through the 2-legged OAuth flow.

I tried to create a ticket on [zendesk](https://linkedin.zendesk.com/), but I got the following response:

> Please note most of our API calls run through 3-legged authorization. We are not assigning 2-legged auth for any of our partners and is not available for any marketing use cases.

Is there an another way to have access to 2-legged auth token? When I try to create a token for my app on this page: https://www.linkedin.com/developers/tools/oauth/token-generator the option for 2-legged is greyed out.

Is it impossible now, to find a linkedin company based on the id?
I know that https://www.linkedin.com/company/123456 will redirect to the company page, but I would like an automated solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'only 2-legged', but as the customer support told you, almost every endpoint that is available as of now, supports 3-legger OAuth2 flows.

That said if you want to retrieve an organization's basic data - which by the way do include profile picture and name - you need to use the `organizationsLookup` endpoint, passing your Bearer access token (3-legged, of course) in the authorization field of your GET request.

#### Lookup organizations

**The request should be formatted like this**: `https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationsLookup?ids=94808959`.

In case you need to pass more than one id, you can do it by using the `List(id1,id2,...)` parameter (`.../organizationsLookup?ids=List(id1,id2)`)

Here's a sample response:

```json
{
    "results": {
        "94808959": {
            "vanityName": "inpilotai",
            "localizedName": "inpilot",
            "name": {
                "localized": {
                    "en_US": "inpilot"
                },
                "preferredLocale": {
                    "country": "US",
                    "language": "en"
                }
            },
            "primaryOrganizationType": "NONE",
            "locations": [],
            "id": 94808959,
            "localizedWebsite": "https://inpilot.ai",
            "logoV2": {
                "cropped": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:D4D0BAQGEQMEdfTdtNA",
                "original": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:D4D0BAQGEQMEdfTdtNA",
                "cropInfo": {
                    "x": 0,
                    "width": 0,
                    "y": 0,
                    "height": 0
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "statuses": {
        "94808959": 200
    },
    "errors": {}
}
```

`https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationsLookup?ids=94808959`

Last thing: you'll need to specify an API version in the header. For the example above I used the `Linkedin-Version: 202209`.

At the following link, you can find the documentation example to learn more about how the entire organization lookup API system works.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-lookup-api?view=li-lms-2023-06&tabs=http#sample-response-1

Comment: this doesn't work for the latest versions, right? for example version 202401

Comment: @titiu7 haven't tested it lately, but the API docs for the organization lookup endpoints still exist [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/organizations/organization-lookup-api?view=li-lms-2024-01&tabs=http#sample-response-1) - using `202401` as the version :)